# Specify version of role in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy, ansible-role

When downloading roles it's possible to specify roles. One of several ways would be with the following `requirements.yml` file:

```
---
- src: https://github.com/jdauphant/ansible-role-ssl-certs
  version: v1.5.2
```

This role could then be downloaded with the following command:

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

How do you then specify which version of a role to use in an Ansible playbook?

```
  roles:
    - jdauphant.ssl-certs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no option to save different versions of a playbook under the same name and  then to specify which version to run in a playbook.

You can:

- "bind" a particular role version to the playbook by downloading out to the `roles` subdirectory of the project directory (the one containing the playbook). Ansible will then use this version before trying roles faced in the system `roles` directory.

  Add `path` to the `requirements.yml`:

  ```
  - src: https://github.com/jdauphant/ansible-role-ssl-certs
    version: v1.5.2
    path: roles/
  ```
- save different versions under different names (i.e. in different directories) system-wide:

  ```
  - src: https://github.com/jdauphant/ansible-role-ssl-certs
    version: v1.5.2
    name: jdauphant.ssl-certs-1.5.2
  ```

  And reference a particular name:

  ```
  roles:
     - jdauphant.ssl-certs-1.5.2
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answerer.  I like your suggested approach, but It's a bit strange that a work around is needed in ansibel for specifying version.

Comment: Ansible Galaxy at this moment does not even have a  option to upgrade a role. You need to delete a role and install it again. Besides Ansible being work in progress, I don't think it makes much sense to implement such feature. It would just create a versioning mess that Ansible was supposed to deal with.